# Using images from MIT licensed software

Tags: open-source-software

I am a software developer and plan to use some icons from [Jenkins CI](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins) in one of our commercial products. Jenkins CI is is distributed under the MIT license, which is designed for software and source code. As of my understanding of the MIT license, in software you can just leave the license header in the source files untouched and don't need to make a copy of the license accessible to the end user. Is that right so far?
If so, how does it apply to the images distributed as part of software under this license? How do I acknowledge the license the right way?

This is the license text:

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2004 Kohsuke Kawaguchi, Sun Microsystems Inc., and a
>   number of other contributors.
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 1):

The license still applies, no matter the file. It may be discouraged, but it's the license you've got, so you've gotta follow it.

Generally, licenses still carry the right to attribution for their authors, so you still need to have a method to attribute them within your application. It's courteous, and within the spirit of open source as well. You don't have to provide a full copy of the license to the end user, but saying that "This picture is licensed under the MIT license" would be sufficient.

You may have fun reading this as well: [Do I need to include the full text of the MIT license in the UI of my app?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/do-i-need-to-include-the-full-text-of-the-mit-license-in-the-ui-of-my-app/6501#6501)